# Как передать параметр целого типа в поток?

Tags: c#

Нужен программный код, который демонстрирует как передать параметр целого типа в поток.

Comment: Используя соответствующий конструктор, см. пример: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart

Comment: не могу понять как?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот так как правильно указал @Андрей NOP

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Main
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        Thread newThread = new Thread(myClass.DoSomeWork);
        newThread.Start(100); // эквивалент myClass.DoSomeWork(100) только в другом потоке
        newThread.Join(); // страховка на случай если основной поток закончится раньше
    }
}


public class MyClass{

    public void DoSomeWork(object data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parameter='{0}'",
            data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Не хватает join.

Comment: @tym32167 Артем Шоб успеть сработать?

Comment: ну да, а то сейчас оно может успеть, а может и не успеть.

Comment: @tym32167 конечно добавил но я думаю что это перестраховка. И блокировка основного потока и только

Comment: Так в этом и смысл, гарантировать что основной поток не завершится до завершения вспомогательного. Сам процесс конечно дождется обоих потоков, но вот дождался ли окно консоли я хз :)

Comment: держи свой плюс :)

Comment: @tym32167 Да конечно спс!!!!